# How to construct an orthonormal basis with almost equal components

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Suppose I want to construct an orthonormal basis for a vector space with "almost" equal magnitude components. I.e. for 2D I can do this exactly:

$\vec{v}_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 1)^T $ and $\vec{v}_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, -1)^T $

2D is a special case though. In general I can't do this so all components are exactly equal. Is there a procedure I could follow to do as good as I can for arbitrary dimension? Can I bound the size of the maximum component of any vector in the basis to be less than or equal to $O(1/\sqrt{d})$ for a $d$ dimensional vector space over the reals?

Thanks!

Comment: What is what you cannot do? Given an orthogonal basis you can certainly normalize each vector, to get an orthonormal basis. By definition the latter has all vectors having equal magnitude (namely 1)...

Comment: Not the magnitude of the vectors. The magnitude of the components

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry!